# C++ search a string

Tags: c++

I am having a really hard time with this problem...

Write a program that reads two strings (that do not contain blanks)
called searchPattern and longSequence.
The program will display in the screen the positions where
searchPattern appears in longSequence.
For example, when
seachPattern is asd
and longSewuence is asdfasdfasdfasdf
(the positions are  0123456789012345)
the program will display 0, 4, 8, 12.
Another example, when
seachPattern is jj
and longSewuence is kjlkjjlkjjjlkjjjkl
(the positions are  012345678901234567)
the program will display 4, 8, 9, 13, 14.

can anyone help?

Comment: what do you have currently? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/346858/198738 ?

Comment: right now i dont know how to get it started its a practice problem and i am really new with strings so i dont even know where to start

Comment: We are not going to write your homework for you. Please write in detail what you started to do and where you stumbled upon problems.

Comment: well a simple solution is just to do a double for loop, if you want to do in linear time you can use Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm.

Comment: I would definitely ask the instructor for more clarification and examples; or you for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. Read in the two strings.  Look up "std::cin" for how to read and "std::string" for how to store the strings.
2. Look at the std::string class's find() method to search for the substring in the long string.

Have a go and then post what you have done on here.  You will find plenty of people happy to help you, but you have to make some effort yourself.  :-)

As a starting point, maybe just write the part that reads in the strings.  When that is working well, you can add features.

Good luck.

Comment: You could also use std::search instead of the string member function.

Comment: @James - You could, but the member function is (allegedly) optimised to work with strings while the generic function is, well generic.

Answer (score 0):

To start thinking about the solution of problems like this, the best way is to think how you would solve it using a pen and paper in as much detail as possible and then try to translate that to code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and start out small and build up.

For example, forget about user I/O, and stick with hard-coded data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(void) // For now, can be modified later.
{
  const char pattern[] = "asd";
  const char sequence[] = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";

  std::string::size_type position = 0;
  const std::string longSequence(sequence);
  position = longSequence.find(pattern, position);
  while (position != std::string::npos)
  {
    cout << "pattern found at position: " << position << endl;
    position = longSequence.find(pattern, position);
  }

  cout << "Paused. Press ENTER to continue." << endl;
  cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
  return 0;
}
```

You may want to convert the above into using a state machine rather than using `std::string::find()`.  Again, this is just a foundation to build upon.

Answer (score -2):

It's a recursive backtracking problem.  Just like getting the mouse out of the maze.  Define your base cases and your paths through the data. In the end all you need is a single function of maybe 15 - 20 lines.

Comment: Recursion for string search? That's a new one for me. Good luck with that.

Comment: @shoosh: When the sought item is truly a pattern (with placeholders) rather than a sequence of fixed characters, backtracking would be quite necessary.  But this question seems to just search for a fixed substring.

Comment: If you're searching for a regexp, back tracking would be an integral part of the FSM you're building. Adding recursion to the pot is a mistake that would cause you to loose all points in the exercise because it demonstrates an extreme misunderstanding of what recursion is for and what are its limitations.

Comment: @shoosh:  It's a naturally recursive problem.  You may not want to use a recursive solution as your final solution for any number of reasons, performance among them, but writing the recursive solution can help the person understand the nature of the problem and come up with an iterative solution afterwards.  I happen to have had almost this exact question on a final exam and they *required* a recursive solution.